# Filesystem show up in `/etc/fstab`, but not using `df -a`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fstab

I don't understand why the following filesystem shows up in `/etc/fstab`, but not using `df -a`:

```
/dev/sdb1 /var/log/apache_logs          reiserfs    user,noauto,rw,exec,suid,user_xattr        0       2
```

I've verified that the folder `/var/log/apache_logs` does indeed exist and can be accessed.

Shouldn't the `df -a` command list ALL filesystems?

```
$ df -a
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ghost-root
                       7583436   1252188   5946020  18% /
proc                         0         0         0   -  /proc
none                         0         0         0   -  /sys
none                         0         0         0   -  /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none                         0         0         0   -  /sys/kernel/debug
none                         0         0         0   -  /sys/kernel/security
udev                    254652       164    254488   1% /dev
none                         0         0         0   -  /dev/pts
none                    254652         0    254652   0% /dev/shm
none                    254652        52    254600   1% /var/run
none                    254652         0    254652   0% /var/lock
none                    254652         0    254652   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sdc1               198321      5763    182319   4% /tmp
/dev/sda5               233335     12670    208217   6% /boot
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/mapper/ghost-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f9f46813-a78a-42e8-a007-53308212ee26 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/sdb1 /var/log/apache_logs          reiserfs    user,noauto,rw,exec,suid,user_xattr        0       2
/dev/sdc1 /tmp         ext2        noexec,nosuid,rw                    0       0
/dev/mapper/ghost-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
$
```

Comment: Only "root" can do that, so I cannot do it, since I'm an ordinary user. Still, that wouldn't answer why `df -a` doesn't show all filesystems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the filesystem mount options in `/etc/fstab` include the `noauto` option. As a result it will **not** be mounted automatically at boot time, nor with `mount -a`.

It will only be mounted with a specific `mount /dev/sdb1` or `mount /var/log/apache_logs` command. Apparently this command has not been issued yet.

`df -a` will list all **mounted** filesystems - including pseudo filesystems like `/proc` or `/sys`, and also duplicate and inaccessible mounted filesystems, but not **unmounted** filesystems.

There's also the `user` option, indicating that even a regular user can mount that specific filesystem into that specific mountpoint, and only the user that mounted it (or root of course) can unmount it again.

Comment: thank you. You write "Apparently this command has not been issued yet."; But why can I cd to `/var/log/apache_logs` then? Is it just because the filesystem already has a directory called that?

Comment: In order to mount a filesystem, there must be a directory that will be used as a mount point; but when the filesystem is not mounted, the mount point will be just an ordinary directory, and that is probably what you're seeing. Frankly, having `/var/log/apache_logs` be an user-mountable directory is rather an odd choice; I wonder why it's done that way.

Comment: do you have any idea why I get the following error, when trying to mount the reiserfs filesystem: `$ mount -t reiserfs /dev/sdb1 /var/log/apache_logs
mount: only root can do that`? Shouldn't it be possible because of the `user` option?

Comment: In order to mount it as a non-root user, you must specify **only** either the device or the mount point, **not** both of them, and **no** filesystem type nor other options. If you specify all the things on the command line, then the `mount` command won't even look into `/etc/fstab`, and will always require you to be root.

Comment: it works thank you. However, the filesystem is mounted `R/W/X` only for root, but `R/X` for my user. Is there any way to mount it as `R/W/X` for my user? Doesn't the `rw` in `user,noauto,rw,exec,suid,user_xattr` imply it should be mounted as `R/W`?

Comment: No, the `rw` option only means "some people may write to the filesystem, **according to the permissions on its files and directories**". It does not give any special permissions to whoever mounted the filesystem. The `ro` option would mean "nobody can write to the filesystem at all" and is occasionally useful for forensics or when trying to salvage data from a damaged filesystem without damaging it any further.

Answer (score 3):

`df` shows mounted filesystems. Your fstab line has `noauto` in it, so it isn't mounted automatically. Presumably it wasn't mounted at the time you ran `df`. The `user` option indicates it's probably meant to be mounted manually by a user other than root.